# How to send a list of selected checkboxes from view to controller

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to work out how I can get the list of selected checkboxes to work using an ActionLink. I think I need to do something clientside with JavaScript but cannot find the relevant code.

The following code works perfectly using a submit button, posting back the selected id's as an array of id's, but I need to have this on a page with other buttons.

```
// the view 
@foreach (var station in Stations)
{
   <input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="@station.StationId" /> 
}    
<input type="submit" value="Save" />

//Controller stub
public ActionResult Action(string [] selected)
```

I have been stuck on this for hours, so maybe I am looking at this the wrong way.

PS. My first post after many many hours reading and learning here.

Comment: are u saying, you want to be able to click on a link and get the content post to the server?  Can I assume those checkboxes are within a form? Ajax post?

Comment: Yes, just click on a link. I haven't used a form in my view (it is a PartialView) but realise I can use @Html.FormBegin() to distinguish the submit buttons from one another. I am not very familiar with Ajax or JavaScript which is why (I suspect) I am struggling here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are not looking for AJAX post. The easiest way to tackle this is to wrap it in the form and call submit function. Here is what your code should look like:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("uraction", "urcontroller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formId" })) { 
    foreach(var station in Stations) {
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="@station.StationId" /> 
    }
}
<a href="#" id="postBtn">Post</a>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#postBtn').click(function() {
            $('#formId').submit();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This (as well as the post by @AliRıza-Adıyahşi) looks like what I want, but I seem to have a conflict with existing JavaScript. My code is in a PartialView that has clientside paging and entering the script above breaks my paging. I will read up on best practices for managing my scripts, and maybe start with a simple page.

Comment: Yeap, usually with AJAX post, you want to get some feed back from server, then either populate the data back to the page  or informs user about a change been made. I am just guessing that you are looking into processing the data then redirect the user to a different page. If that's the case, my solution will be more suitable.

Comment: You guess correct. I have a list of objects (paged but only dealing with one page at a time at this stage - no need to remember selections from previous pages). I want to be able to select the objects, then call an action to process the selected objects: Delete, Flag, etc...  Thanks for replying.

Comment: Please mark my post as solution if you find this working for you. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

SomeButtons or links to post checkboxlist values

```
<a href="#" id="someButton">Post</a>
//or buttons, helpers and any elements to trigger ajax post...
```

**CheckboxList:**

```
<div id="MyDiv">
    @foreach (var station in Stations)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="@station.StationId" /> 
    }  
</div>
```

**Scripts:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#someButton').click(function() {
        var list = [];
        $('#MyDiv input:checked').each(function() {
            list.push(this.name);
        });
        // now names contains all of the names of checked checkboxes
        // do something with it for excamle post with ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Action","Contoller")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { Parameters: list},
            success: function (result) {
                alert("success")!
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("error!");
            }
        });   //end ajax
    });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Action(string [] Parameters)
```

if I got it right :)